# java - NullPointerException on ClassNode.accept

Tags: java, class, java-bytecode-asm, minecraft-forge

**Hello,**

Whenever I try to accept a ClassWriter with a ClassNode, it throws a NullPointerException. Is there a way for me to fix this?

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:340)
    at net.winneonsword.WCClient.asm.WCClassTransformer.transform(WCClassTransformer.java:119)
    at net.winneonsword.WCClient.asm.WCClassTransformer.transform(WCClassTransformer.java:64)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.runTransformers(LaunchClassLoader.java:274)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:172)
    ... 9 more
```

Here is the spot it's talking about:

```
ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

node.accept(writer);

bytes = writer.toByteArray();
```

Here is the full method:

```
private byte[] transform(PatchInfo patch, byte[] z){

    boolean patched = false;
    byte[] bytes = z;

    ClassNode node = new ClassNode();
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(bytes);

    reader.accept(node, 0);

    WCLog.fine("Patching Class: %s", new Object[] { patch.target });

    HashMap<MethodNode, MethodNode> replace = new HashMap();

    for (MethodNode target : node.methods){

        for (MethodInfo method : patch.methods){

            if ((method.name.equals(method.name) || method.name.equals(method.mappedName))
                    && (method.desc.equals(method.desc) || method.desc.equals(method.mappedDesc))){

                MethodNode replacement = this.getReplacementMethod(patch, method);

                replace.put(target, replacement);
                WCLog.fine("Successfully Patched: %s at %s", new Object[] { method.name, method.desc });

                patched = true;

            }

        }

    }

    if (patched){

        for (MethodNode method : replace.keySet()){

            MethodNode replacement = replace.get(method);

            node.methods.remove(method);
            node.methods.add(replacement);

        }

        ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

        node.accept(writer);

        bytes = writer.toByteArray();

    }

    return bytes;

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message would suggest that your `node` is `null` when you're calling `accept()` on it. Do you initialize it in some way before that line?

Comment: In the full method posts it says ClassNode node = new ClassNode();

Comment: @WinneonSword: In the full method, OP is not calling `accept()` on a `ClassNode` object rather than on a `ClassReader` object, so the stacktrace cannot be from that method.